# Ubuntu 16.04 no sound Hardware found

Tags: ubuntu, audio, alsa

My [Lenovo ThinkCentre 910t](https://psref.lenovo.com/Detail/ThinkCentre/ThinkCentre_M910_Tower?M=10MN000Hxx) [desktop](https://download.lenovo.com/pccbbs/pubs/m910t/en/index.html?linkTrack=PSP:ProductInfo:UserGuide) PC with Intel UHD 630 graphics lost audio, maybe after an upgrade; when I check the sound settings it shows no hardware:
[image]

I have tried this:

```
sudo alsa force-reload
Unloading ALSA sound driver modules: (none loaded).
Loading ALSA sound driver modules: (none to reload).
```

And then:

```
sudo modprobe -v snd-hda-intel
modprobe: FATAL: Module snd-hda-intel not found in directory /lib/modules/4.15.0-47-generic
```

Any suggestions to fix it?

Session info:

> ```
> model name    : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7700 CPU @ 3.60GHz
>        description: Motherboard
>        product: 3106
>        vendor: LENOVO
>        physical id: 0
>        version: SDK0J40709 WIN 3259614826284
>        slot: Default string
>
> Distributor ID:   Ubuntu
> Description:  Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS
> Release:  16.04
> Codename: xenial
> System Information
>         Manufacturer: LENOVO
>         Product Name: 10MNS1AG00
>         Version: ThinkCentre M910t
>         Wake-up Type: Power Switch
>         Family: ThinkCentre M910t
> ```

```
lspci -v | grep -i audio
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH HD Audio
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GK208 HDMI/DP Audio Controller (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Bitland(ShenZhen) Information Technology Co., Ltd. GK208 HDMI/DP Audio Controller
```

Comment: Suggest you search for solutions at https://askubuntu.com/search?q=sound%20missing Also, what's your PC's make and model?  Please so `cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep "model name" && sudo lshw | grep -A5 "Moth"` then click [edit] to add the facts to your question. Please do not click Add Comment, please use [edit] instead. Editing tips are at https://unix.stackexchange.com/editing-help#code .

Comment: I have added the information.

Comment: Have added as well. Thanks

Comment: Looks like you have two sound adapters; the Intel 200 Series PCH HD Audio and the Nvidia / Bitland(ShenZhen) Information TechnologGK208 HDMI/DP Audio Controller (rev a1).